# windows service and my problem

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

i want to write a windows service app.
i'm beginer.
now my question is :if the user loging off what event happen OnStop() or OnShutdown()??
after the user logining what happen OnStart() or OnContinue()??
thanks alot.

Comment: Windows services are not affected by users logging in or out. They run on their own session. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @CesarGon:you mean if the user loging off windows service dosn't do any thing??

Comment: Exactly. The service keeps running. See my answer below for a reference.

Comment: @CesarGon:can i stop the service when the user loging off and then start it??

Comment: If you want to do that, then I don't suggest you implement a service. Services are designed to run unattended. If you want to run a process during an interactive user session, create a regular app and place a shortcut to the executable into the StartUp folder of that user.

Comment: @CesarGon:excusme,how can i do it??

Comment: If you know how to create a shortcut in Windows, you can do it. :-) Create your app, then find the StartUp folder ("C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" on Windows 7) and then put a shortcut to your app's executable into theat folder. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows services are not affected by users logging in or out. They run on their own session. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=VS.100).aspx) out, especially the "Service Lifetime" section.

Answer (score 1):

none of what you said because a Windows Service does not run in the same Windows Session of the logged in user so it's fully independent and unaffected from user logins.

If you want to better understand the service lifecycle events you could log a message in a text file or use Log4net and log the event name in every method like OnStart, OnStop, OnContinue and so on and then you try to restart the computer and you play a bit with stop/pause/restart from the Services panel from Control Panel.

Comment: i know all you said,but can you suggest me another solution to get user's details,i don't want to use eventlog of server windows on my local network.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Services in windows start up when the system starts up and shuts down when the machine is shutting down.  The user logging off usually doesn't cause a service to shut down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that runs only when the user is logged in and runs interactively in the user session, you should look at the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You can schedule a task which runs only when the user is logged on.